# statusText: "Gateway Timeout" on react rails fetch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, heroku, proxy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0sFlwz0YvU

I'm at 20:09 in this tutorial.  I set up my proxy like he did:

```
  "proxy": {
    "/api":{
      "target": "http://localhost:3001/api"
    }
  },
```

but got an error:

"When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string."

So I made a file client/src/setupProxy.js with this code:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api',
        { target: 'http://localhost:3001' }
    ));
}
```

Now I am getting a 504 gateway timeout error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I made that tutorial proxy cannot be an object try:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/api"
```

or

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

Your request would have to be:

```
fetch(`/api/login`,...
```